# Writing in only one row

Tags: python, file-handling

I need to merge some string from different file to an output file but only in one rows! This is my actual code:

```
eannuli=open('eannuli_spec_prova_ciao.reg','r',)
fov_c7=open('23849_fov_c7_ciao.reg','r')
fov7=fov_c7.read()
psr=open('psrc-ciao_mod.reg','r')
psrc=psr.read()

i = 1

for ean in eannuli:
    if os.path.exists('region%s.reg' %i):
        i += 1
    region=open('region%s.reg' %i, "w")
    print(fov7,'*',file=region,sep='*',end='')
    print(ean,file=region,sep='',end='')
    print(psrc,file=region,end='')
    region.close()
    break


eannuli.close()
fov_c7.close()
psr.close()
```

I also tried with the write() function but wihtout success. For each variable it make a new row.

Answer (score 0):

From your post it looks like you are reading the lines from one file and then writing the lines into another file. It is putting new lines on each line because the lines from the file you are reading have new line characters at the end. You can fix this by stripping the new line character of the end of the line. Something like this:

```
for ean in eannuli:
    if os.path.exists('region%s.reg' %i):
        i += 1
    region=open('region%s.reg' %i, "w")
    region.write(fov7)
    region.write(ean.rstrip())
    region.write(psrc)
    region.close()
    break
```